# Proper designer-first reall world app example in Scala Lift

Tags: lift

Trying to learn lift, and i'm looking for a somehow bigger example than HelloWorld (something like spring pet-clinic).

Especially i'm looking at advanced templating in designer friendly manner (as less code in snippets as possible).

I tried to look at example Lift apps https://github.com/lift/examples
But they heavily mix html in their snippets https://github.com/lift/examples/blob/master/nuggets/skittr/src/main/scala/com/skittr/snippet/UserMgt.scala

So can anyone link me to a source of real world app that uses designer-friendly templating?

Comment: A lot of the demo apps you will find use the older `bind` style syntax as your example above shows - not the designer friendly CSS Selectors. There are some resources like: http://cookbook.liftweb.net/#HTML which show use cases for the newer templates, but I don't know of too many fully implemented sample sites that are lift based that have been updated recently.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm. My hobbie project partially corresponds to what you ask, I think.) https://github.com/vn971/roboCup

It's not all good, I started it when only learning Scala and I see now that it has poor decision choises in some places. But, for example, you can see code-free templates here:
https://github.com/vn971/roboCup/blob/master/src/main/webapp/swiss.html

Ajax bindings can be seen here:
https://github.com/vn971/roboCup/blob/master/src/main/webapp/admin.html

It unfortunately uses html in the code somewhere, too. It's also very little, uses actors (both lift's and akka), has no database at all (only the state of the tournament matters and it's not persisted).

Answer (score 0):

try [lift in action](http://www.manning.com/perrett/) book , there is a build of a big web app almost step by step and the project is also on [github](https://github.com/timperrett/lift-in-action) so you can download it also from there